# How to subset data with several conditions in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have a text file consisting of 6 columns as shown below. the measurements are taken each 30 mint for several years (2001-2013) and sometimes differ each 32 or 39 for certain days. I want to extract and select certain range from this data.

to read the file:

```
 LR=read.table("C:\\Users\\dat.txt", sep ='', header =TRUE)

header:

   now to subset for 2008 and 2009 and hour =23 I used:

  dat=subset(wg, Year > 2007 & Year < 2010 & hour == 23 & mint==30)
```

that worked fine but as I said there is different mints that I want to consider also.So I did this:

```
  dat=subset(wg, Year > 2007 & Year < 2010 & hour == 23 & mint==30 | 32 | 39 |40 |41 | 49 | 31)
```

but the output `dat` is not correct and there are years out of the range i.g, 2003, 2004
Any help please

Comment: I think you need `mint %in% c(30, 32, 39, 40, 41, 49, 31)`

Comment: Okay, then I will put it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
dat <- subset(wg, Year > 2007 & Year < 2010 & hour == 23 & 
                 mint %in% c(30, 32, 39, 40, 41, 49, 31))
```